# IOS: Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcode5, phonegap-build

I am newbie here (this is my first question) on this forum, I am given a task to set up IOS  phonegap app, that uses a very old version of phonegap  1.8 , when I try to build that app I get this error

```
Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device
```

I know the question is already being asked and answered as well, I have tried that solution too but didn't find any luck

here I explain more about the issue

```
Platform : IOS

Cordova Version : 1.8

X-Code Version : 5.0
```

and this is error that I get

**what I have tried?**

1) I have tried changing the "Architecture" settings to $(ARCHS_STANDARD).

2) I have tried changing "Build Active Architecture Only" to YES for Debug mode.

3) I have tried changing "Valid Architecture" to "armv7 ,armv7s,armv6".

4) I have tried Clean, Clean folders, Delete derived data, reset the content of simulator.

5) I have tried to change " Compiler for C/C++/Objective c "  to Default compiler(Apple LLVM 5.0)

I am now really stuck here for full day, thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

1.go to build Settings-> select Architectures-> click on others.. and add $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)

2.go to build settings-> select valid Architectures ->add armv7 ,armv7s,armv64

it works for me

Comment: thank you for your help. as mention in my question i have already tried this. I appreciate this.

Comment: you have used armv6, use "armv64"

Comment: There is no "armv64". Its called "arm64" without a v!